# combination of words based on a list of list of characters

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I am given sets of multiple numbers such as 6837. I have a dictionary as such which basically says what characters I can use for each number, basically the numbers on a phone keys, as follows:

```
letters = {
    "2": ["a","b","c"],
    "3":["d",'e','f'],
    '4':['g','h','i'],
    '5':['j','k','l'],
    '6':['m','n','o'],
    '7':['p','q','r','s'],
    '8':['t','u','v'],
    '9':['w','x','y','z']}
```

So I created a list of list to show what each set of numbers can be and for 6837 I have:

```
[['m', 'n', 'o'], ['t', 'u', 'v'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['p', 'q', 'r', 's']]
```

So I need to combine all possible words where 
first character has to be : m or n or o
2nd character : t or u or v
and so on. 
I have tried `itertools.combinations`, not getting it right. I can do brute force of taking each character and append the rest in order and create a list of words. But there has to be a python way of doing this which is very clean. Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

def keypad(number):
    letters = {'2':['a', 'b', 'c'],
               '3':['d', 'e', 'f'],
               '4':['g', 'h', 'i'],
               '5':['j', 'k', 'l'],
               '6':['m', 'n', 'o'],
               '7':['p', 'q', 'r', 's'],
               '8':['t', 'u', 'v'],
               '9':['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']}
    return [''.join(i) for i in product(*[letters[i] for i in number])]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    words = keypad('6837')
    print(words)
```

Which prints:

```
['mtdp', 'mtdq', 'mtdr', 'mtds', 'mtep', 'mteq', 'mter', 'mtes', 'mtfp', 'mtfq', 'mtfr', 'mtfs', 'mudp', 'mudq', 'mudr', 'muds', 'muep', 'mueq', 'muer', 'mues', 'mufp', 'mufq', 'mufr', 'mufs', 'mvdp', 'mvdq', 'mvdr', 'mvds', 'mvep', 'mveq', 'mver', 'mves', 'mvfp', 'mvfq', 'mvfr', 'mvfs', 'ntdp', 'ntdq', 'ntdr', 'ntds', 'ntep', 'nteq', 'nter', 'ntes', 'ntfp', 'ntfq', 'ntfr', 'ntfs', 'nudp', 'nudq', 'nudr', 'nuds', 'nuep', 'nueq', 'nuer', 'nues', 'nufp', 'nufq', 'nufr', 'nufs', 'nvdp', 'nvdq', 'nvdr', 'nvds', 'nvep', 'nveq', 'nver', 'nves', 'nvfp', 'nvfq', 'nvfr', 'nvfs', 'otdp', 'otdq', 'otdr', 'otds', 'otep', 'oteq', 'oter', 'otes', 'otfp', 'otfq', 'otfr', 'otfs', 'oudp', 'oudq', 'oudr', 'ouds', 'ouep', 'oueq', 'ouer', 'oues', 'oufp', 'oufq', 'oufr', 'oufs', 'ovdp', 'ovdq', 'ovdr', 'ovds', 'ovep', 'oveq', 'over', 'oves', 'ovfp', 'ovfq', 'ovfr', 'ovfs']
```

Comment: Can the output be modified so I can have 'over' instead of [('o','v','e','r')]. Thanks.

Comment: I edited this to use `.join` for each letter group.  I also removed the extra iteration that was returning duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like you want [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> opts = [['m', 'n', 'o'], ['t', 'u', 'v'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['p', 'q', 'r', 's']]
>>> for item in itertools.product(*opts):
...   print item
... 
('m', 't', 'd', 'p')
('m', 't', 'd', 'q')
('m', 't', 'd', 'r')
('m', 't', 'd', 's')
('m', 't', 'e', 'p')
('m', 't', 'e', 'q')
('m', 't', 'e', 'r')
('m', 't', 'e', 's')
('m', 't', 'f', 'p')
('m', 't', 'f', 'q')
('m', 't', 'f', 'r')
('m', 't', 'f', 's')
('m', 'u', 'd', 'p')
('m', 'u', 'd', 'q')
('m', 'u', 'd', 'r')
('m', 'u', 'd', 's')
('m', 'u', 'e', 'p')
('m', 'u', 'e', 'q')
('m', 'u', 'e', 'r')
('m', 'u', 'e', 's')
('m', 'u', 'f', 'p')
('m', 'u', 'f', 'q')
('m', 'u', 'f', 'r')
('m', 'u', 'f', 's')
('m', 'v', 'd', 'p')
('m', 'v', 'd', 'q')
('m', 'v', 'd', 'r')
('m', 'v', 'd', 's')
('m', 'v', 'e', 'p')
('m', 'v', 'e', 'q')
('m', 'v', 'e', 'r')
('m', 'v', 'e', 's')
('m', 'v', 'f', 'p')
('m', 'v', 'f', 'q')
('m', 'v', 'f', 'r')
('m', 'v', 'f', 's')
('n', 't', 'd', 'p')
('n', 't', 'd', 'q')
('n', 't', 'd', 'r')
('n', 't', 'd', 's')
('n', 't', 'e', 'p')
('n', 't', 'e', 'q')
('n', 't', 'e', 'r')
('n', 't', 'e', 's')
('n', 't', 'f', 'p')
('n', 't', 'f', 'q')
('n', 't', 'f', 'r')
('n', 't', 'f', 's')
('n', 'u', 'd', 'p')
('n', 'u', 'd', 'q')
('n', 'u', 'd', 'r')
('n', 'u', 'd', 's')
('n', 'u', 'e', 'p')
('n', 'u', 'e', 'q')
('n', 'u', 'e', 'r')
('n', 'u', 'e', 's')
('n', 'u', 'f', 'p')
('n', 'u', 'f', 'q')
('n', 'u', 'f', 'r')
('n', 'u', 'f', 's')
('n', 'v', 'd', 'p')
('n', 'v', 'd', 'q')
('n', 'v', 'd', 'r')
('n', 'v', 'd', 's')
('n', 'v', 'e', 'p')
('n', 'v', 'e', 'q')
('n', 'v', 'e', 'r')
('n', 'v', 'e', 's')
('n', 'v', 'f', 'p')
('n', 'v', 'f', 'q')
('n', 'v', 'f', 'r')
('n', 'v', 'f', 's')
('o', 't', 'd', 'p')
('o', 't', 'd', 'q')
('o', 't', 'd', 'r')
('o', 't', 'd', 's')
('o', 't', 'e', 'p')
('o', 't', 'e', 'q')
('o', 't', 'e', 'r')
('o', 't', 'e', 's')
('o', 't', 'f', 'p')
('o', 't', 'f', 'q')
('o', 't', 'f', 'r')
('o', 't', 'f', 's')
('o', 'u', 'd', 'p')
('o', 'u', 'd', 'q')
('o', 'u', 'd', 'r')
('o', 'u', 'd', 's')
('o', 'u', 'e', 'p')
('o', 'u', 'e', 'q')
('o', 'u', 'e', 'r')
('o', 'u', 'e', 's')
('o', 'u', 'f', 'p')
('o', 'u', 'f', 'q')
('o', 'u', 'f', 'r')
('o', 'u', 'f', 's')
('o', 'v', 'd', 'p')
('o', 'v', 'd', 'q')
('o', 'v', 'd', 'r')
('o', 'v', 'd', 's')
('o', 'v', 'e', 'p')
('o', 'v', 'e', 'q')
('o', 'v', 'e', 'r')
('o', 'v', 'e', 's')
('o', 'v', 'f', 'p')
('o', 'v', 'f', 'q')
('o', 'v', 'f', 'r')
('o', 'v', 'f', 's')
```

Comment: Thanks, you did answer exactly what I asked. Though the full answer will be "over;overlying;overcome;overcoat;overgrowth" from a corpus. I guess I need to find all words that start with over. But you did make it more clear thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First create a suitable list of letters for your given numbers and then use Python's [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to create all available combinations for those letters as follows:

```
from itertools import product

letters = [[""], [""], ["a","b","c"], ["d",'e','f'], ['g','h','i'],
    ['j','k','l'], ['m','n','o'], ['p','q','r','s'], ['t','u','v'], ['w','x','y','z']]

for combo in product(*(letters[x] for x in [6,8,3,7])):
    print combo
```

For 6837 you will get the following output:

```
('m', 't', 'd', 'p')
('m', 't', 'd', 'q')
('m', 't', 'd', 'r')
('m', 't', 'd', 's')
('m', 't', 'e', 'p')
('m', 't', 'e', 'q')
('m', 't', 'e', 'r')
('m', 't', 'e', 's')
('m', 't', 'f', 'p')
('m', 't', 'f', 'q')
('m', 't', 'f', 'r')
('m', 't', 'f', 's')
('m', 'u', 'd', 'p')
('m', 'u', 'd', 'q')
('m', 'u', 'd', 'r')
('m', 'u', 'd', 's')
('m', 'u', 'e', 'p')
('m', 'u', 'e', 'q')
('m', 'u', 'e', 'r')
('m', 'u', 'e', 's')
('m', 'u', 'f', 'p')
('m', 'u', 'f', 'q')
('m', 'u', 'f', 'r')
('m', 'u', 'f', 's')
('m', 'v', 'd', 'p')
('m', 'v', 'd', 'q')
('m', 'v', 'd', 'r')
('m', 'v', 'd', 's')
('m', 'v', 'e', 'p')
('m', 'v', 'e', 'q')
('m', 'v', 'e', 'r')
('m', 'v', 'e', 's')
('m', 'v', 'f', 'p')
('m', 'v', 'f', 'q')
('m', 'v', 'f', 'r')
('m', 'v', 'f', 's')
('n', 't', 'd', 'p')
('n', 't', 'd', 'q')
('n', 't', 'd', 'r')
('n', 't', 'd', 's')
('n', 't', 'e', 'p')
('n', 't', 'e', 'q')
('n', 't', 'e', 'r')
('n', 't', 'e', 's')
('n', 't', 'f', 'p')
('n', 't', 'f', 'q')
('n', 't', 'f', 'r')
('n', 't', 'f', 's')
('n', 'u', 'd', 'p')
('n', 'u', 'd', 'q')
('n', 'u', 'd', 'r')
('n', 'u', 'd', 's')
('n', 'u', 'e', 'p')
('n', 'u', 'e', 'q')
('n', 'u', 'e', 'r')
('n', 'u', 'e', 's')
('n', 'u', 'f', 'p')
('n', 'u', 'f', 'q')
('n', 'u', 'f', 'r')
('n', 'u', 'f', 's')
('n', 'v', 'd', 'p')
('n', 'v', 'd', 'q')
('n', 'v', 'd', 'r')
('n', 'v', 'd', 's')
('n', 'v', 'e', 'p')
('n', 'v', 'e', 'q')
('n', 'v', 'e', 'r')
('n', 'v', 'e', 's')
('n', 'v', 'f', 'p')
('n', 'v', 'f', 'q')
('n', 'v', 'f', 'r')
('n', 'v', 'f', 's')
('o', 't', 'd', 'p')
('o', 't', 'd', 'q')
('o', 't', 'd', 'r')
('o', 't', 'd', 's')
('o', 't', 'e', 'p')
('o', 't', 'e', 'q')
('o', 't', 'e', 'r')
('o', 't', 'e', 's')
('o', 't', 'f', 'p')
('o', 't', 'f', 'q')
('o', 't', 'f', 'r')
('o', 't', 'f', 's')
('o', 'u', 'd', 'p')
('o', 'u', 'd', 'q')
('o', 'u', 'd', 'r')
('o', 'u', 'd', 's')
('o', 'u', 'e', 'p')
('o', 'u', 'e', 'q')
('o', 'u', 'e', 'r')
('o', 'u', 'e', 's')
('o', 'u', 'f', 'p')
('o', 'u', 'f', 'q')
('o', 'u', 'f', 'r')
('o', 'u', 'f', 's')
('o', 'v', 'd', 'p')
('o', 'v', 'd', 'q')
('o', 'v', 'd', 'r')
('o', 'v', 'd', 's')
('o', 'v', 'e', 'p')
('o', 'v', 'e', 'q')
('o', 'v', 'e', 'r')
('o', 'v', 'e', 's')
('o', 'v', 'f', 'p')
('o', 'v', 'f', 'q')
('o', 'v', 'f', 'r')
('o', 'v', 'f', 's')
```